# why group sum qty by item qty not zero but it show many number with letter e "1.1102230246251565e-16" with aggregate mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregate

Everyone please help me with sum qty by item, in fact It is zero but when I sum with aggregate it's always show the number like that **1.1102230246251565e-16** any solution to fix. you can see my items as below  is my collection with aggregate.

Example it just sample data with aggregate please help me or any recommendation. I'm not sure with sum different with what to expect.

```js
let data[
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5ca1d52e63102d00072fa433"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : 10
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5cde757ba9b05421b2fd4c02"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : 7
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5ccbca18b4448606bb6b32d9"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -10
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5ccbef392dee2a084cd54a59"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -6
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5ccbf5632dee2a084cd54bb3"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : 20
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc0ae7f2f55c0a0745fa3e"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -10
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5c9315ae1dfa340d69b85033"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -1
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5cccf4149e6bf007522a4569"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : 35
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5cde7b03758b1a25055b9c4b"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -0.967
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5cde7b03758b1a25055b9c50"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -9
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5ccfa8380d4b880630c9c1b3"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -10
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5ccfa85d0d4b880630c9c1c7"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -5
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5ccfaf7c0d4b880630c9c1f5"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -5
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5c935b486f6338291f31f907"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -10
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5c9987c5ad6cb100076860b7"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : 25
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5ccfe4a388ed8d07d6328f3e"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -20
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5c999660ad6cb100076860fe"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : 25
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5cde73a8a9b05421b2fd4bff"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -1.033
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5ca424bac87f4f0007d833ba"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -10
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5cad54eb9c7a210007ac456a"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -20
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5cb03fc66554c600078fe7d4"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : 20
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5cc65fbd122c9300076f9f44"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -5
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5cd152ba3790d300077bdc23"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -10
        },
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5cd234653790d300077bdc7a"),
          "itemId" : "91",
          "qty" : -9
        }
      ]
//Aggregate sum qty by item   
data.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {itemId:'91'}
    },
    
    {
        $group: { 
            _id: "$itemId",
            onhand:{$sum:'$qty'}
        }
    }
]).toArray()
// And the result it is not zero but it show like that 

//{
// "_id" : "91",
// "onhand" : 1.1102230246251565e-16
//}
```

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/R4hRtSSJhfx **When?**

Comment: I run on mongobooster I see onhand is 0 but on json it show "onhand" : 1.1102230246251565e-16 like that